# Enabling sockets.io in sails to run on multiple ports

Tags: socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I have to set sails app where I can have socket.io connections on multiple ports - for example authentication on port 3999 and data synchronization on port 4999.

Any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question yesterday and it seems that yours is also similar to mine, here's what I'm going to implement.

Given that you will have multiple instances that are going to work on different ports, they won't be able to talk to each other directly and that breaks websocket functionality.

It seems that [there are multiple solutions to this](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) (sticky sessions vs using the pub/sub functionality of Redis), I chose Redis. There's a module for that called [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis). You also need [emitter module](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter), it's here.

If you choose that route, no matter how many servers (multiple servers with multiple instances) OR many instances on a single server you run your app on, it will function without a problem thanks to Redis.

At least that's what I know for now, been searching for a few days, haven't tried it yet.

Not to mention, you can use Nginx for load balancing, like below. (Copied from socket.io docs)

```
upstream io_nodes {
  ip_hash;
  server 127.0.0.1:6001;
  server 127.0.0.1:6002;
  server 127.0.0.1:6003;
  server 127.0.0.1:6004;
}
```

Comment: Finally ended up to creating another httpserver in bootstrap.js

var customAppServer = http.createServer(sails.hooks.http.app);
    var customAppSocket = io(customAppServer);
    customAppServer.listen('3001');
    module.exports.customAppSocket = customAppSocket;
    customAppSocket.on('connection', function(socket) {
        sails.config.customRoutes.setListeners(socket);
        socket.emit('connected', { hello: 'world' });
    });